# How does Airflow Celery worker manage Queue mirroring in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, airflow, celery

We are setting up Airflow with Celery Executor using RabbitMQ.

We see that there are multiple Queues created by the Celery Worker on the Rabbit MQ UI:

[image]

Since Celery does not yet support Quorum Queue type, it creates classic queues. For the configuration part, do we still need to setup mirroring policies for all the queues that airflow celery workers create? Or is it an overkill ? What is the correct procedure to implement this?